# neo4j 2.3 removing all attributes

Tags: properties, neo4j

I removed all nodes and relationships from my DB, but would also like to remove all property keys. Might have been easier if I had started in the reverse order. Is there a way of doing this through Cypher?

Comment: if you removed all nodes and relationships, there will be no more properties although some old cached key names might still appear on the left side in the browser

Answer (score 2):

To completely reset everything back to an empty db, shut down Neo4j, do an `rm -rf data/graph.db` and start it again.

BE WARNED: this will completely and unconditionally destroy your graph.

There is no way to remove previously used property keys using Cypher.

Answer (score 0):

cypher:

```
match (n)-[r]-() delete r,n
```

have to clean up all relations and nodes from bd